# titles not showing correctly in angular material tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using angular material tabs but there is something wrong with my implementation and it gives me this result (on Chrome and Firefox):

[image]

As you can see the tab titles are truncated.
Here is my implementation:
HTML:

```
<md-tabs>
    <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
        <md-tab-label>{{tab.titre}}</md-tab-label>
        <div class="md-tabs-content">
            content tab
        </div>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

JS:

```
var tabs = [];
for(i=0;i<3; i++){
    tabs.push({

        titre: 'title'
    });
}
$scope.tabs = tabs;
$scope.selectedTab = 0;
```

Added the plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nFMFmaGpLUwJPxRd1TpT?p=preview

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: Your plnkr doesn't compile

Comment: Maybe it would work better if you used the same version of Angular Material CSS and JS files. Your CSS is version 0.7.0 and your JS is version 0.8.2. To fix the plnkr compile problem, just remove all of the unnecessary dependencies from your app/controller (you're not using them in this simple example).

Comment: Working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uDaFVcDy8DG23EDOlrzw?p=preview)

Comment: Your working plnkr works fine for me.  What browser are you using?

Comment: @Tom assuming you're referring to my link: it works for me too. But only after I updated the Angular Material CSS to be the same version as the JS.

Comment: I'm using the same version of angular material css and js and it is still not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [Angularmaterial docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.tabs/directive/mdTab) for `md-tab`

**Please note that if you use `<md-tab-label>`, your content MUST be wrapped in the `<md-tab-body>` tag. This is to define a clear separation between the tab content and the tab label.**

So can you trying changing your code to:

```
<md-tabs>
    <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
        <md-tab-label>{{tab.titre}}</md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body class="md-padding">
            content tab
        </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```